# dimension error while converting code from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am working on conversion of code from matlab to python.

for values,

```
N = 100
V = [[ -7.94627203e+01  -1.81562235e+02  -3.05418070e+02  -2.38451033e+02][  9.43740653e+01   1.69312771e+02   1.68545575e+01  -1.44450299e+02][  5.61599000e+00   8.76135909e+01   1.18959245e+02  -1.44049237e+02]]
```

V is numpy array.

```
for i = 1:N
    L(i) = sqrt(norm(v(:,i)));
    if L(i) > 0.0001
        q(:,i) = v(:,i)/L(i);
    else
        q(:,i) = v(:,i)*0.0001;
    end
end
```

I have converted this code to :

```
L = []
q = []


for i in range(1, (N +1)):
    L.insert((i -1),np.sqrt( np.linalg.norm(v[:, (i -1)])))
    if L[(i -1)] > 0.0001:
        q.insert((i -1), (v[:, (i -1)] / L[(i -1)]).tolist())
    else:
        q.insert((i -1), (v[:, (i -1)] * 0.0001).tolist())
q = np.array(q)
return q, len_
```

But, in matlab the resultant dimensions are 3 x 4 but I am getting 4 x 3 in python. Can anyone let me know where I am doing mistake?

Comment: What version of numpy are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting lists of length 3 into `q`.  When you finish the loop that creates `q`, `q` is a list of 4 items, where each item is a list of length 3.  So `np.array(q)` creates an array with shape 4x3.  You could change the second-to-last line to this:

```
q = np.array(q).T
```

Or, you can use numpy more effectively to eliminate all the explicit `for` loops.  For example, if you are using numpy 1.8, the `norm` function accepts an `axis` argument.

Here's vectorized version of your code.

First, some setup for this example.

```
In [152]: np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

In [153]: np.random.seed(111)
```

Create some data to work with.

```
In [154]: v = 5e-9 * np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(3, 4))

In [155]: v
Out[155]: 
array([[  0.000e+00,   0.000e+00,   0.000e+00,   0.000e+00],
       [  1.000e-08,   5.000e-09,   1.000e-08,   1.000e-08],
       [  1.000e-08,   0.000e+00,   5.000e-09,   0.000e+00]])
```

Compute the square root of the norms of the columns by using the argument `axis=0` in `numpy.linalg.norm`.

```
In [156]: L = np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(v, axis=0))

In [157]: L
Out[157]: array([  1.189e-04,   7.071e-05,   1.057e-04,   1.000e-04])
```

Use `numpy.where` to select the values by which the columns of `v` are to be divided to create `q`.

```
In [158]: scale = np.where(L > 0.0001, L, 1000.0)

In [159]: scale
Out[159]: array([  1.189e-04,   1.000e+03,   1.057e-04,   1.000e+03])
```

`q` is has shape (3, 4), and `scale` has shape (4,), so we can use broadcasting to divide each column of `q` by the corresponding value in `scale`.

```
In [160]: q = v / scale

In [161]: q
Out[161]: 
array([[  0.000e+00,   0.000e+00,   0.000e+00,   0.000e+00],
       [  8.409e-05,   5.000e-12,   9.457e-05,   1.000e-11],
       [  8.409e-05,   0.000e+00,   4.729e-05,   0.000e+00]])
```

Repeated here are the three lines of the vectorized code:

```
L = np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(v, axis=0))
scale = np.where(L > 0.0001, L, 1000.0)
q = v / scale
```

Comment: how to do len = sum(sqrt(sum(v.*v)))/N; with numpy 1.8?

Comment: The Matlab expression `sqrt(sum(v.*v))` gives the Euclidean norm of the columns of `v`, so it can be expressed with numpy as `np.linalg.norm(v, axis=0)`. Then `len_ = np.linalg.norm(v, axis=0).sum()/N`.  If `N` is the number of columns of `v`, then summing and dividing by `N` is just the mean, so `len_ = np.linalg.norm(v, axis=0).mean()`.